# blender Python Error - flip fluid is not baking - unknown error

Tags: python, animation, add-on, fluid-simulation

Every thing ok when i try to bake the flip fluid simulation it's come. the error related to addon because without flip fluid added the domain can be baking.
how to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the FLIP Fluids addon to a more recent version that is compatible with your Blender version. Specifically for Blender 3.0 compatibility, you will need to use FLIP Fluids version 1.2.0 or later.

From the [FLIP Fluids addon Installation Troubleshooting](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Addon-Installation-and-Uninstallation#baking-error-attributeerror-arrayarray-object-has-no-attribute-tostring):

> **Baking Error: AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'tostring'**
>
> If you are receiving this error message in Blender 2.93 or later, this will indicate that there is a compatibility error between your installed FLIP Fluids addon version and installed Blender version. You will need to update your FLIP Fluids addon version to at least v1.0.9b or later. FLIP Fluids version 1.0.9b adds compatibility support for Blender 2.93. FLIP Fluids version 1.2.0 adds compatibility support for Blender 3.0.

Hope this info helps!